# Issue with gam function in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, gam

I'm trying to fit a generalized additive logistic regression model, but I'm getting a strange error:

```
gam_object = gam(event ~ s(time) + ., data = lapse_train, family = "binomial") 

Error in terms.formula(gf, specials = c("s", "te", "ti", "t2")) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

Why would it be telling me there is no data argument here when there obviously is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the error message is from a call to `terms.formula()` which is called inside the function. This function doesn't see the `data=` parameter you passed to `gam()`.

If you check out the `?formula.gam` help page you'll see that

> The formulae supplied to gam are exactly like that supplied to glm except that smooth terms, s, te, ti and t2 can be added to the right hand side (**and . is not supported in gam formulae**).

You could expand the formula before passing it to `gam` via the standard `terms()` function. For example

```
gam_object <- gam(terms(event ~ s(time) + ., data=lapse_train), 
    data = lapse_train, family = "binomial")
```

You didn't supply any sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so it's not possible to verify that this will work for you.